# Is there any way to return more than 10 results per page using the Amazon product API?

Tags: amazon-product-api

I see that it has a limit of 10 results per request for the product ItemSearch api.  Is there any way that I can return more, or perhaps use the batch api to return more?

I'm using the node.js apac library.

Comment: I hope this help https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/MaximumNumberofPages.html

Comment: that's the max number of pages - but not the items per page

Answer (score 1):

Each page in the amazon api response can only include upto 10 items http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html#Description

Comment: I know, but is there a way around that, perhaps using the batch api to make a request for multiple pages at a time?

Comment: Yes you can use the batch api to make multiple requests at a time. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/PerformingMultipleItemLookupsinOneRequest.html. You have to give the ids of the items separated by commas. It should then return results for each item id

Comment: but if it's an itemsearch by keyword - I can't pass in the itemids, can I just pass a keyword and only vary the page?

Comment: No. If you use batch requests then you have to pass the asin as the itemid.   See the note at the bottom on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BatchandMultipleOperationRequests.html.

Answer (score -1):

Use "perPage": 10000 in your payload. 10000 records will be return in one shot.